# Missing Request data on failed samples

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter 2.12 and execute test with following properties set -

```
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml \
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true \
```

When there is a failure then I can see info under Response Data tab in View Results in tree as - 500, 404 or any other error
but Request tab only shows "GET" with out more information.

For my test, GET request has more specific user information which I would like to analyze to find out which GET requests caused 500 etc error.

I don't see any property like - Jjmeter.save.saveservice.request.on_error and I don't want to save all the data as it would grow huge.
Did I miss any setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample_variables` property in combination with the [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) to get the request data stored for failed requests only in main .jtl results file as follows:

1. Add Beanshell Listener so all the "interesting" requests are in its scope (same level or higher)
2. Put the following code into the Listener's "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!sampleResult.isSuccessful()) {
       vars.put("url", sampleResult.getUrlAsString());
       vars.put("cookies", sampleResult.getCookies());
       vars.put("query", sampleResult.getQueryString());
       vars.put("data", sampleResult.getSamplerData());
       //etc.
   }

   else {
       //clean up old values
       vars.remove("url");
       vars.remove("cookies");
       vars.remove("query");
       vars.remove("data");
   }
   ```
3. Add the following line to *user.properties* file:

   sample_variables=url,cookies,query,data,foo,bar,etc

Next time you run the test you will see desired request details in the .jtl results file.

References:

- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: I am running test in distributed mode, do I have to specify it in user.properties file of each jmeter client instance?

Comment: Not necessarily, it is enough to do it on master only, you should see something like `INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [url, cookies,...] ` in jmeter.log file.

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Strange behaviour. Adn when it works, customer variables putted on wrong httpsample (on next).